# Appending a New Vector to a Vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm creating a vector that itself will contain a vector, using this code:

```
vector<vector<short>> pixelData;
```

However, I start with an empty vector, and I would like to append a new vector as the first element, but I don't know how to construct a vector without assigning it to a variable. Right now, I'm doing:

```
pixelData.push_back(vector<short> (x, y));
```

Where pixelData is my containing vector, and I'm constructing a new vector inside with two short values.

Comment: Please specify which version of C++ you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to append a new `vector`, which contains two elements with value `x` and `y`, you should use [initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11),

```
pixelData.push_back(vector<short> {x, y});
```

or just

```
pixelData.push_back({x, y});
```

Check the constructors of `std::vector` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are not constructing a vector with 2 short values, you are invoking this constructor:

```
explicit vector::vector(size_type count, const T& value = T())
```

which initializes the vector with a capacity of `count` by coping `value` to each cell.

To create an empty vector just call the empty constructor, eg `vector<short>()`, but if you know the capacity just use it, eg `vector<short>(size)` to avoid internal reallocation.